# Link one resource file to another instead of duplicating

Tags: android, android-resources

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699650/android-emulator-displays-hebrew-resources-correctly-but-device-doesnt/8716894#8716894), in order to make Hebrew available on all devices, I need to maintain two similar files of each resource type, one in `values-iw` and another in `values-he`. Having a ready-to-use `strings.xml`, I was wondering if there's a way to "link" the files in one of these folders to the files in the second folder instead of making an alias for each string ([exampled here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)).

Thanks!

Comment: Delete one of the two files. Edit the other one. Copy-paste it. Rename the newly pasted file as the one you deleted. Done.

Comment: @Rotwang I'm aware of this option as well. I wonder if there's a way to link one to another, so I wouldn't have to deal with it every time I modify a string.

Comment: As per the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html): `A single string that can be referenced from the application or from other resource files (such as an XML layout).` It **seems** promising... ;)

Comment: Why to you need to link them? Don't all string values get compiled into a the R.java file and are accessible by `R.string`?

Comment: @cricket_007 In order not to edit the files twice. As both `_iw` and `_he` are needed for Hebraic, if you want to support older devices.

Comment: @Rotwang This is pretty much similar to the example I attached - making each string link to its corresponding string in the other file. It prevents me from modifying both files on any change, but still requires extra work upon adding (or removing) a string.

Comment: @NeriaNachum I unfortunately don't know any other way.